# Compiling the "at" command for my mips toolchain

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

While cross compiling with the following command :-
`./configure CC=/data/designs/pweth-s-t1501/trunk/software/embedded/ar9341/linux/build/gcc-4.3.3/build_mips/staging_dir/usr/bin/mips-linux-uclibc-gcc --host=mips-linux`
During the course of the compilation I am getting this kind of an error.
`checking Trying to compile a trivial ANSI C program... configure: error: Could not compile and run even a trivial ANSI C program - check CC.`
My question is that does not the binary know that it is being cross-compiled so it is natural that the compiled binary will not be running on my machine.
Can anybody please tell me a workaround for the same problem?

Comment: Did this happen during the compile or during the configure?

Comment: It happened during the configure.If you may require i can post the code of the Makefile or something @Jim

Comment: Look for a configure flag that turns off that check.  I'm assuming this must be a package that isn't often cross-compiled.  In a pinch you could try editing the configure to remove the check.  But I'd try to find the flag first.

Comment: I have removed that check altogether but now am still stuck on the compilation.I by passed the checks altogether.One more questin though if you want to addd a feature in your current toolchain most importantly it not being in the standard package.how do you incorporate that feature.? @Jim

Comment: Your question is a bit too general for me to understand.  How is the compile failing?

Comment: `lex.yy.c:1261: undefined reference to `yywrap'
`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [at] Error 1`.`    This is the exact error that is coming. @Jim

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34287/discussion-between-rohan-majumdar-and-jim)

Comment: you need library -lfl